# JasperReports - Numerical Values Are Not Recognized When Exporting to Excel

Tags: export, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, jasperserver

I've created a report in iReport which contains numerical values. These values are of type *java.math.BigDecimal*. After exporting the report to xls (using iReport) the cells containing those numbers are correctly recognized. It is possible to change the number format, add decimal places and so on. To accomplish that I added the following line to the report definition:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
```

My problem is that the export to Excel does not work on the server (JasperServer 4.1.0). I already changed the property *net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type=true* in the file *jasperreports.properties*. Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. I've also checked the spring-bean *xlsExportParameter* and the property *detectCellType* is also set to *true*. Did I miss anything or could there be a problem with the exporter on the server?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change ***`detectCellType`*** property in ***`applicationContext.xml`*** file (you can find it in jasperserver\WEB-INF\ folder) at JasperServer.

```
<bean id="xlsExportParameters" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.common.XlsExportParametersBean">
    <property name="detectCellType" value="true"/>
    <property name="onePagePerSheet" value="false"/>
    <property name="removeEmptySpaceBetweenRows" value="true"/>
    <property name="removeEmptySpaceBetweenColumns" value="true"/>
    <property name="whitePageBackground" value="false"/>
    <property name="ignoreGraphics" value="true"/>
    <property name="collapseRowSpan" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreCellBorder" value="true"/>
    <property name="fontSizeFixEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="maximumRowsPerSheet" value="0"/>
    <property name="xlsFormatPatternsMap" ref="formatPatternsMap"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I've already the value of detectCellType in applicationContext.xml and it is also set to true.